# quickSort segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, recursion, quicksort, coredump

I know there have been multiple answers towards my problem and I understand why it is but my main problem is how to overcome this error. I know I am trying to access memory that I do not have access to but I just don't see how I am doing this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int arr[] = {4,5,2,1,3};
int lengd = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

void swapNumber(int arr[], int i, int j){
     int tmp = arr[i];
     arr[i] = arr[j];
     arr[j] = tmp;
}

void partition(int arr[], int i, int j){
     int pivot = arr[j];
     while (i <= j) {
          while (arr[i] < pivot){
               i++;
          }
          while (arr[j] > pivot){
               j--;
          }
          if (i <= j) {
               swapNumber(arr, i, j);
               i++;
               j--;
          }
     }
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
      int i = left;
      int j = right;

      partition(arr,left,right);


      if (left < j){
          quickSort(arr,left, j);
      }
      if (i < right){
          quickSort(arr, i, right);
      }
}

int main(){
    quickSort(arr,0, lengd-1);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
     }
}
```

The error occurs when I run the quickSort function inside of the quickSort function. I don't have a clue what to do.

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger to catch the crash in action, and to locate where in your code it happens? When the crash happens, what is the values of all involved variables? What is the recursion depth (i.e. how many recursive calls is there on the call stack)? Have you tried using a memory-debugger such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you?

Comment: or at least put a `std::cout << i << ", " << j << std::endl;` in your partition function and see what's happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your numbers won't be modified in your `partition` function, you should change its signature to receive *reference*:

```
void partition(int arr[], int& i, int& j)
```

and everything will work fine.

It's easy to spot such flaws using a debugger or well-placed console messages!

Comment: Thanks man, you really helped me out and showed me a cool new trick :)